# Expected closest distance to a point

Tags: probability, statistics

Consider $X_1, X_2, \dots X_n $ all I.I.D Uniform$[0,1]$. What is the expected distance from a uniformly selected point to its closest neighbour? I know that the expected point closest greater than it is $\frac{1}{n+1}$. And the same result for expect point closest less than it is $\frac{1}{n+1}$. This is clearly an upper bound on our answer.

Notice the problem has a lack of symmetry. That is the expected closest point to $0$ is $\frac{1}{n+1}$ But the expected closest point to $\frac{1}{2}$ is $\frac{1}{2(n+1)}$

We do however have symmetry around one half. I wanted to condition the expectation on the selected point and integrate. I was thinking of using the law of total expectation. The sigma-algebra being generated by the number of points in $[0,2x]$ and using linearity rescale the expected closest point to $\frac{1}{2}$. However when using the Tower Rule we have a Binomial RV on the denominator and this is tricky.

Reforming the problem as this: Let $X \sim $Uniform$[0,1]$ Then $Y_1 , Y_2 , \dots Y_{n-1}$ be IID Uniform $[0,1]$  and we are after 
$\mathbb{E}$[Min$_{i \in [1,n-1]}$$\{ |X - Y_i| \}$]

We could then find the CDF, differentiate for PDF and integrate for expectation, due to symmetry around $\frac{1}{2}$ consider only $x \in[0,\frac{1}{2}]$

Which of my methods seems most fruitful ? Is there much simpler way of doing this?

If it helps here is a plot with values $n=2$ to $n=20$ [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first approach works, with a little effort.

Let's suppose the first point is at $x$ (assuming wlog $0 < x <\frac12$) and we want to know the probability the nearest of the other points is at least $y$ away in absolute distance.  Then

- for $0\le y \le x$ this probability is $(1-2y)^{n-1}$
- for $x\lt y \le 1-x$ this probability is $(1-x-y)^{n-1}$

So the expected distance of the nearest other point is

$$\int_0^x (1-2y)^{n-1}\, dy + \int_x^{1-x} (1-x-y)^{n-1}\, dy = \frac{1}{2n}\left(1+(1-2x)^n\right)$$  which almost gives the answers you had when $x=0$ and $x=\frac12$.  Perhaps you forgot there are $n-1$ rather than $n$ other points.

We can then find the overall expected distance of the nearest point, remembering to undo the restriction on $x$:

$$2 \int_0^{1/2} \frac{1}{2n}\left(1+(1-2x)^n\right) \,dx = \frac{n+2}{2 n \left( n+1\right) }$$

and pasting my graph over yours, these points seem to fall exactly on those in your graph

[image]

Comment: Lovely stuff Henry, Thanks for this :)